# Цикл вложения циклов в циклы

Tags: java

Мне нужно получить список всех дискретных локаций из дискретного n-мерного пространственного диапазона.

Это можно сделать легко двойным вложенным циклом для двухмерного пространства, тройным для трёхмерного и тд. Но если мне нужна возможность в любой момент использовать 20-мерное пространство, не писать же мне по способу обработки для каждого n вплоть до бесконечности.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: обратитесь к рекурсии

Comment: а без рекурсии можно как то?

Comment: найдёшь вариант , расскажи, я ничего не придумал

Comment: В случае 20-мерного пространства и кучи вложенных циклов получится алгоритм со сложностью O(N^20). Не говоря уже о том, что добавить _каждую_ точку в некий список такого 20-мерного пространства не получится из-за ограничений на размер коллекции.

Comment: 2^20 прожевать можно.

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak, любая рекурсия переписывается в итерацию, любая итерация переписывается в рекурсию.

Answer (score 1):

Если индексы в массиве воспринимать как цифры некоторого числа, то алгоритм прибавления единицы перебирает все комбинации индексов:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] limits = {2, 3, 4};

        int[] digits = new int[limits.length];

        for (; ; ) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
            int i;
            for (i = limits.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                ++digits[i];
                if (digits[i] < limits[i]) {
                    break;
                }
                digits[i] = 0;
            }
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac Temp.java && java Temp
> [0, 0, 0]
> [0, 0, 1]
> [0, 0, 2]
> [0, 0, 3]
> [0, 1, 0]
> [0, 1, 1]
> [0, 1, 2]
> [0, 1, 3]
> [0, 2, 0]
> [0, 2, 1]
> [0, 2, 2]
> [0, 2, 3]
> [1, 0, 0]
> [1, 0, 1]
> [1, 0, 2]
> [1, 0, 3]
> [1, 1, 0]
> [1, 1, 1]
> [1, 1, 2]
> [1, 1, 3]
> [1, 2, 0]
> [1, 2, 1]
> [1, 2, 2]
> [1, 2, 3]
> ```

Comment: Что означает запись for (; ; )?

Comment: Идиома бесконечного цикла. `while (true)`.